# Can't Escape $ (Dollar Sign) in Environment Variable in Dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to put a password in a command in a Dockerfile. The problem is it has a $ in it, so the variable get evaluated but the $ is in the value so it tries to evaluate that afterwards.

The Dockerfile is called from a bash script, so to get the password into the file I did something like:

```
read -p "Input Username:" Username
read -s -p "Input Password:" Password
docker build --build-arg Username=$Username --build-arg Password=$Password...
```

And in the Dockerfile I have:

```
ARG Username
ARG Password
```

Then within the Dockerfile, I have tried this:

```
curl -u "$Username:$Password"
```

It gets expanded to something like

```
curl -u "Username:Pass12$34"
```

Which doesn't work as it tries to evaluate $34 as a variable. I tried using single quotes but that didn't evaluate the variable at all. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `curl -u "$Username:${Password//\$/\\$}"`?

Comment: Can you expand your post to show how you get the environment variable into the Dockerfile? If not done correctly, there's a high risk of leaking the password.

Comment: @HansKilian added more context

Comment: BTW, in general, it should be `--build-arg Username="$Username" --build-arg Password="$Password"` -- leaving out those quotes means that a password with spaces could be split into more arguments to `docker build`.

Comment: Beyond that... can you extend your Dockerfile into a [mre] complete enough I can run it myself and see the incorrect expansion? (The symptom you're describing is what happens if your variable is substituted into a script _before_ that script or command is parsed by a shell, rather than exposed as an environment variable for a shell to substitute _after_ parsing is complete)

Comment: i'm not exactly sure about how vars are expanded in dockerfiles but in shell: `$this:$that` is problematic.  use curly braces to protect: `"${this}:${that}"`.

Comment: @keithpjolley, they're not _that_ problematic. `$this:$that` is fine; it's `$this_$that` that would be a problem if not changed to `${this}_$that`. Leaving out curly braces is, as a rule, _much_ less likely to cause issues than leaving out quotes.

Comment: only if you can guarantee that there are no spaces in `$this` or `$that`.

Comment: @keithpjolley, spaces are equally problematic in both `$this` and `${this}` cases; curly braces change nothing about how spaces are handled.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it seems like adding double quotes to the build-arg fixed it somehow!

Comment: @keithpjolley, you're thinking about suppression of string-splitting; that's done by quotes, not curly braces.

Comment: well, no. but that's ok.

Comment: @keithpjolley, _please_ demonstrate a case where `$this` and `${this}` vary in terms of whitespace handling; I'll gladly wait.

Comment: try `curl -u '$Username:$Password'`. I.e. with single quotes.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy -. the quotes are for spaces, the braces are to protect against the ":"  have a nice day.

Comment: @keithpjolley, ...to give you a starting point, as an example where `${this}` and `"${this}"` differ: `this='two words'; printf 'A: %s\n' ${this}; printf 'B: %s\n' "${this}"` -- you'll see it behaves _exactly_ the same as `this='two words'; printf 'A: %s\n' $this; printf 'B: %s\n' "$this"`

Comment: @keithpjolley, the `:` doesn't need to be protected against because it isn't a character that can be parsed as part of a variable name. That's why you _would_ need braces if it were an underscore (which can be used in a name), but _don't_ need them with a `:` (which cannot). My first comment directed to you said as much.

Comment: @keithpjolley, (and you _did_ claim it was a whitespace difference: *"only if you can guarantee if there are no spaces in `$this` or `$that`"*; if you want to disengage, delete your incorrect comments and I'll delete my responses to them).

Comment: well, i'll keep using double quotes and you keep being you.

Comment: @keithpjolly, ... I'm trying to figure out why we're at odds with each other here. Earlier in this thread, I viewed your insistence on bringing up quotes as an attempt at deflection (to avoid needing to defend your claim that curly braces add any meaningful value in the OP's use case), but am wondering if that's a misinterpretation, and you saw my leaving quotes out of code samples (where I thought everyone already agreed they were necessary and could thus be assumed) as implicitly claiming that they weren't needed, despite the explicit text of my comments contadicting any such implication.

Comment: If that's so, I suppose I owe an apology for failing to read things in the most charitable possible light. It's _only_ the claims regarding braces that I ever made any attempt to challenge above, and I believe a sober rereading will confirm same.